# Access array index by string name in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `public Image[]` to get many `Image UI` that exist on scene from **Unity Editor** .

Now i wanna deactivate one or more of them from scene by it's name.

But i can't access this array items by string name of `Images` .only i can access by int number for index like `Images[0]`

I tried before `Dictionary`  Class and other solutions on forums but i can't find a way .

How can i do this ?

Comment: Well, using `Dictionary<string, Image>` does sound like the way forward. Where did you get stuck with that? Creating the dictionary, or using it? Are you able to use LINQ? If so, just `var dictionary = Images.ToDictionary(image => image.Name);` or similar should work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Array**:

Use a for loop to loop over the image array then compare the name. If they match, deactivate them.

```
public Image[] image;

void activateImage(string imageName, bool enable)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < image.Length; i++)
    {
        if (image[i].name == imageName)
        {
            image[i].enabled = enable;//Good for performace
            // OR
            //image[i].gameObject.SetActive(enable);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

Activate

```
activateImage("nextImage", true);
```

Deactivate

```
activateImage("nextImage", false);
```

**For Dictionary**:

```
Dictionary<string, Image> image = new Dictionary<string, Image>();

void activateImage(string imageName, bool enable)
{
    if (image.ContainsKey(imageName))
    {
        image[imageName].enabled = enable;//Good for performace
        // OR
        //image[imageName].gameObject.SetActive(enable);
    }
}
```

To add Image to Dictionary:

```
public Image myImage;
image.Add(myImage.name, myImage);
```

or

```
image.Add("myImageName", myImage);
```

Comment: @LumbusterTick Thanks and you are right. It is just that I avoid using linq when it is not the **only** solution in Unity. I use linq a-lot in a normal Windows form App but not in Unity unless if really really required. The reason is performance and memory allocation.